# How to implement the loop function already implemented in python with scala

Tags: scala, for-loop

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYdKr.png)

### **I write some code in scala but i am stuck on the loop function.**

```
import math._

object Haversine {
val R = 6372.8  //radius in km

def haversine(lat1:Double, lon1:Double, lat2:Double, lon2:Double)={
val dLat=(lat2 - lat1).toRadians
val dLon=(lon2 - lon1).toRadians

val a = pow(sin(dLat/2),2) + pow(sin(dLon/2),2) * cos(lat1.toRadians) * cos(lat2.toRadians)
val c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a))
R * c
}

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
println(haversine(36.12, -86.67, 33.94, -118.40))
 }
}
```

---

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import Haversine.haversine

object Position {

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

// create Spark DataFrame with Spark configuration
val spark= SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()


// Read csv with DataFrame
val file1 = spark.read.csv("file:///home/aaron/Downloads/taxi_gps.txt")
val file2 = spark.read.csv("file:///home/aaron/Downloads/district.txt")

//change the name
val new_file1= file1.withColumnRenamed("_c0","id")
  .withColumnRenamed("_c4","lat")
  .withColumnRenamed("_c5","lon")
val new_file2= file2.withColumnRenamed("_c0","dis")
  .withColumnRenamed("_1","lat")
  .withColumnRenamed("_2","lon")
  .withColumnRenamed("_c3","r")

//count

 }
}
```

I am not familiar with scala,it is quite a tough question for me.
I hope you guys can help me,thx!

Answer (score 0):

Before implementing you need to define and implement method `cal_distance` out side `main` method but in same class

```
def cal_distance(lon: Float, lat: Float, taxiLon: Float, taxiLat: Float) : Float = {
    val distance = 0.0f
    // write your geopy scala code here
    distance
  }
```

You code should in Scala should be similar to something as below

```
    new_file2.foreach(row => {
      val district = row.getAs[Float]("dis")
      val lon = row.getAs[Float]("lon")
      val lat = row.getAs[Float]("lat")
      val distance = row.getAs[Float]("r")
      var temp = 0
      new_file1.foreach(taxi => {
        val taxiLon = taxi.getAs[Float]("lon")
        val taxiLat = taxi.getAs[Float]("lat")
        if(cal_distance(lon,lat,taxiLon,taxiLat) <= distance) {
          temp+=1
        }
      })
      println(s"district:${district} temp=${temp}")
    })
```

Comment: It would be better to use a `foldLeft` instead of a `foreach` with a mutable variable. Also, since this seems to be **Spark**, I believe you can not use a DF inside a DF.

Comment: I am wondering If there's actually a performance boots of `foldLeft` over `foreach` ? @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez

Comment: WDYM? Both will perform mostly the same and you should not care. If you care about performance of the sum of some values, then use plain arrays and a while loop. And then, it may still be too slow due to the JVM so you may need to use a native language like **C** and then if it is still too slow, you may need to turn on the compiler optimizations and compile for the most precise architecture of your CPU, and you can optimize it even more. The point of FP is not to write the most performant code, is to write more readable and reusable code. - Anyways, if those are DF, the `foreach` won't work.

Comment: You can check for `foreach` in `Dataset.scala` file. Thanks to implicit conversion from Dataframe to Dataset. @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez

Comment: I did not say there won't be a `foreach` method, I said it won't work. A DataFrame is a distributed dataset, thus its foreach is executing on different machines, modified different copies of `temp` so the real `temp` in the driver node won't be affected and will stay as a zero.